# in perl(v5.14.2), why is map{+0,0}() correct but map{0,0}() not?

Tags: perl

It seems that perl treat {+0,0} as a BLOCK and {0,0} an EXPR
But why? Is that a special provision?

If I want to make sure that the {} is an anonymous hash whatever the braces contain, do I have to put a `+' before {} ?

thanks.

Comment: `{; ...}` is more idiomatic (and a better hint for the reader) for forcing parsing as a BLOCK. `+` is usually used for the opposite (`+{...}` to force parsing as an EXPR).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why?  Because it could be either, and the parser doesn't look far enough ahead to know for sure by the time it needs to decide.

Do you have to put a '+' before {} to have it be treated as an anonymous hash constructor regardless of the contents of the {}?  Yes.

Comment: It's interesting though that `perl -MO=Deparse -e "map { +0,0 } 1..2"` outputs something that you can't use in original script.